# Currency Converter not working in Android

Tags: android

I have an android program that converts currencies.  The problem is that the currencies aren't converting.  Here is my code.

```
package com.example.currencyconverter;

import java.text.DecimalFormat;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.RadioButton;
import android.widget.RadioGroup;
import android.widget.Spinner;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class MainActivity extends Activity 
                          implements OnClickListener, 
                          OnItemSelectedListener{

    EditText edittextdollars;
    EditText edittexteuros;
    TextView dollars;
    TextView euros;
    RadioButton dtoe;
    RadioButton etod;
    RadioGroup radiogroup;
    Spinner spinner1;
    Spinner spinner2;
    Button calculate;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        addListenerOnButton();
    }

    private void addListenerOnButton() {
        spinner1 = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spinner1);
        spinner2 = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spinner2);
        calculate = (Button) findViewById(R.id.calculate);
    }
    @Override
    public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1, int arg2,
            long arg3) {    
    }

    @Override
    public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> arg0) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    }


    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        String text = spinner1.getSelectedItem().toString().trim();
        String text2 = spinner2.getSelectedItem().toString().trim();
        if (text.equalsIgnoreCase("Dollar") && text2.equalsIgnoreCase("Euro")) {
            convertDollarstoEuros();
        }
        Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this,
            "OnClickListener : " + 
            "\nSpinner 1 : "+ String.valueOf(spinner1.getSelectedItem()) + 
            "\nSpinner 2 : "+ String.valueOf(spinner2.getSelectedItem()),
        Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }

    public void convertDollarstoEuros() {

        double val = Double.parseDouble(edittextdollars.getText().toString());
        DecimalFormat df = new DecimalFormat("###.##");
        edittexteuros.setText(df.format(val*0.77));
        }

    protected void convertEurostoDollars() {
        double val = Double.parseDouble(edittexteuros.getText().toString());
        DecimalFormat df = new DecimalFormat("###.##");
        edittextdollars.setText(df.format(val*1.3));

        }

    protected void convertEurostoEuros() {
        double val = Double.parseDouble(edittexteuros.getText().toString());
        DecimalFormat df = new DecimalFormat("###.##");
        edittextdollars.setText(df.format(val*1));
    }

    protected void convertDollarstoDollars() {
        double val = Double.parseDouble(edittextdollars.getText().toString());
        DecimalFormat df = new DecimalFormat("###.##");
        edittexteuros.setText(df.format(val*1));
    }

}
```

The toast part is working, but the currency conversion isn't (please look at onClick function).  I have two spinners.  Either the toast is just showing, or when I click calculate, the app is crashing.

Comment: When a question is closed as too localized, it means that that question is so specific to your individual problem that it is not useful for other people to find.   An example "localized question" is this: "Hey Rohodude, is there a red car outside my window now?".  How would you answer this question?  Was the car ever there?  Has it moved?  Which window am I talking about?  The question is so narrow, that it spams the website and anybody else who lands on this site is aggravated that they can't find what they need.  So try to make questions more general.

Comment: Alright, sorry, this was my first question on SO.  I have learned a lot since and now I know how to  write a question on SO.  Also, how does my question get this much attention after 6 months?

Comment: I saw your latest post on adding integers in a list.  I'm going back in time to make sure you are not spamming the site with useless artefacts.  If you want to learn more about what it takes to become a moderator you could burn these podcasts to CD and listen to them: https://soundcloud.com/stack-exchange/  These are the founders of this site, Jeff and Joel, and they give elite tips on how to gain reputation the fastest and how to work your way up toward moderator status.  And lots of tips on how to be the kind of programmer who could build this website.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`edittexteuros` doesn't seem to have been initialised.

In your `onCreate()` make sure you initialise it like so:

```
edittexteuros = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.name_of_your_edit_text_id_in_xml);
```

Otherwise when you try and `setText` on it in `convertDollarstoEuros()` you will get a `NullPointerException`.

Same goes for all your other View elements of course. You've done it for `spinner1`, `spinner2`, and `calculate` but all the others have not been set up.

Comment: Thank you, I will try to do what you said.

Comment: Is everything else fine?